# Where "AND" not functioning as expected

Tags: powershell

I am pulling Windows event logs using Get-EventLog and removing log events I don't want to see using source and eventid as criteria.  When I do parse using where, the values are note respected.  For example if I do

```
$Events = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $computer -LogName Application 
$events | ft source, eventid
```

I see the following:

```
Source                            EventID
------                            -------
AutoEnrollment                         34
```

If I do:

```
$events |
    ?{($_.Source -ne "AutoEnrollment" -and $_.EventID -ne 14)} |
    ft source, eventid
```

The results are empty, which puzzles me because clearly the eventid does not match. I expect if I were evaluating against `$_.eventid -ne 34`, then the results would not show that event. This worked when I wrote the code on PowerShell 2 back in 2012.  Now on v5.1 it fails to properly evaluate.

Has something changed that I should be aware of, or did I screw it up initially?  If I AM doing this wrong, any suggestions on how to say "where event not match specified criteria as a set" so that source=autoenrollment and eventid=34 will show up, but events with source=autoenrollment and eventid=14 will not.

Comment: change the `-and` to `-or` - otherwise you're only excluding AutoEnrollment events that _also_ happen to have event id 14

Comment: that is quite strange. i don't have that Source, so i used `ESENT`. when i set the two items to `ESENT` and `666`, i get NO ESENT items ... even tho the numbers are 102, 301, & 302. i don't know why, tho. [*blush*]  [win7x64, ps5.1]

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - unless i am totally misunderstanding the OPs goal ... he wants to exclude ONLY the items that match the two values. what happens instead is that ALL the items with the source value are excluded ... even tho they have different EventID values.

Comment: Yes, and @MathiasR.Jessen suggestion is right. `NOT(A AND B)` is not the same as `NOT(A) AND NOT(B)`, it's equivalent to `NOT(A) OR NOT(B)`. Why this used to work on PS2 is odd.

Comment: I would rewrite as `?{-not ($_.Source -eq "AutoEnrollment" -and $_.EventID -eq 14)}`, which is arguably more human-readable.

Comment: @mjsqu could not agree more! @ Lee_Dailey from the "false positive" example he gives it reads like he wants to exclude events that match _any_ of the two conditions

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Using NOT(a and B) fixed it.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around the reasoning for the existing interpretation.  I had thought that was being interpenetrated together by putting it in parenthesis, IE, requiring that both conditions be true to match.    I mean, shouldn't that be the case, and "NOT(A) OR NOT(B)", be used for an OR condition?  If both AND and OR mean OR, then something seems wrong with the interpretation, no?

Comment: This even says "true when both statements are true".  So in my original evaluation, both statements would not have been true, so it should not have matched, right?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

These two posts by mjsqu answered the question:

es, and @MathiasR.Jessen suggestion is right. NOT(A AND B) is not the same as NOT(A) AND NOT(B), it's equivalent to NOT(A) OR NOT(B). Why this used to work on PS2 is odd. – mjsqu 21 hours ago

I would rewrite as

```
... |? {-not ($_.Source -eq "AutoEnrollment" -and $_.EventID -eq 14)}
```

... which is arguably more human-readable.